# apt update/apt upgrade won't work after using GNOME Software

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, software-center

I have to kill `aptd` everytime I use GNOME Software in order to get `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt upgrade` to work. If I dont kill `aptd` then I get this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Is there something I can do to make `aptd` stop automatically when I quit GNOME Software?

Comment: Before using command line, software center and anything else that uses dpkg or apt as a backend must be closed

Comment: @ravery read the last line in the question. I am not asking why I am getting the "could not get lock" error, I am asking how I can make `aptd` automatically stop after quitting GNOME Software (if possible).

Comment: it should automatically stop. That is why I suggested to be sure nothing else is holding it open

Comment: @ravery you should've said that in your first comment. I will check if anything is using it after closing `gnome-software`